# How to query nested object (with a particular key, value pair) in an array (in firebase) with python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am new to Firebase and have started working with it. I have stored the data, and a document is in the following format:

```js
{
    title: "Tera Hone Laga Hoon",
    album: "Ajab Prem Ki Ghazab Kahani"
    artists: [
        {name: "Atif Aslam", thumbnail: "https://download.org/At98yvnsh-oid"},
        {name: "Joi Barua", thumbnail: "https://download.org/Joi-0osmaa"}
    ]
}
```

**I want to write a query to select all documents having artist with name `Atif Aslam`**

I have used the following code:

```py
db.collection("songs").where(
    u"artists", 
    u"array_contains", 
    {"name": "Atif Aslam", "thumbnail": "https://download.org/At98yvnsh-oid"}
)
```

*This code works fine, but the thumbnail url does not match for every case; the url for some cases is different.*

**So, is there any way I could query throughout the array with a particular key, `like if the array contains an object of key-value pair of {name: "Atif Aslam"}`**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore `array_contains` operation can only match exact, complete items in the array field. It cannot be used to perform partial matches.

As usual when dealing with NoSQL databases, the solution is to add more data to allow the specific use-case.

So if you want to be able to search just on artist name, you can add an addition array field with just the artist names. Something like:

```
artist_names: ["Atif Aslam", "Joi Barua"]
```

With that field in place, you can perform the query:

```
db.collection("songs").where(
    u"artist_names", 
    u"array_contains", 
    u"Atif Aslam"
)
```